# conditional float of <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am building a chat client and want to `float-right` if the message is from the active user and then `float-left` when the message is received from the other end user. I tried adding `float:right` in my css itself, but when I do that it makes my list items go horizontal instead of vertical.

JavaScript

```
if (user.id === msgsender.id) {
    $("#messages").append($("<div class= bubble-r><li>/div>").text(msg));
} else {
    $("#messages").append($("<div class=bubble><li></div>").text(msg));
}
function render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id="messages">
          <div />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

CSS

```
.bubble-r {
  overflow-x: hidden;

  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  background: #0072c6;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.bubble {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #cad5d7;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Have you played around with `clear:both`?

Comment: What is this `<div />` I see? `<div>` is not a void element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you need a wrapper on a block level for each bubble text. The basic approach would be to insert a `li`, that inside has a `div.bubble` that floats if the message is from the sender.

The adding would be like this:

```
function addMessage(user, msg) {
    var $li = $("<li></li>");
    var $div = $("<div/>")
      .addClass("bubble")
      .text(msg)
      .toggleClass("bubble-sender", user.id === msgsender.id) //If sender, it will add "bubble-sender" class
      .appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo("#messages");
}
```

and then, you only make the `.bubble-sender` class to float right.

Here's a fiddle with the code
https://jsfiddle.net/Robertroid/Lxd78ayf/29/

Also fixed some things, like redundant css (both bubbles have a `.bubble` class, for shared style), changed `ul` for `ol` (makes sense since chat text is ordered by arrival) and that `li` is the direct child of `ol`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Don’t apologise for fixing stuff, broken things should be fixed. But please do explain the fixes you made, and why you made them. :)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance with jQuery, but with this approach how would I I guess untoggle "bubble" so I can change the background. The bubble class overrides it.

Comment: In that case, have two separated classes for each one (sender and receiver), and give each one separate backgrounds, and toggle them on opposite conditions. I'll update the fiddle to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is you are not using `clear` to clear the floats. This is why it is all horizontal.

Now lets tidy this up and make it more meaningful.

Elements can have more than one class, seprerated by a space. Have a common class for `bubble` then have classes for `sender` and `receiver`

That will give you something like:

```
//Div is an invalid child of ul, use li 
var userClass = user.id === msgsender.id ? "sender" :"receiver";
$("#messages").append($("<li class='bubbble'>").addClass(userClass).text(msg));

//Got rid of div from the below, it is invalid html
function render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <ul id="messages">              
         </ul>
       </div>
     );
   }
```

CSS

```
.bubble {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  //Need to clear floats to get each
  //Message on a new line.
  clear:both;
}

.sender {
   background: #cad5d7;
   float:left;   
}    

.receiver {
  background: #0072c6;
  float:right;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

When when rendered should give you:

```css
.bubble {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 100px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: arial;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-bottom:2px;
    }

    .sender {
       background: #cad5d7;
       float:left;
       clear:both;
     }

    .receiver {
      background: #0072c6;
      float:right;
      clear:both;
      color:#FFF;
    }

    ul {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
  <li class="bubble sender">Hi from sender</li>
  <li class="bubble receiver">Hi from reciever</li>
  <li class="bubble sender">Whats up?</li>
  <li class="bubble sender">Having a good day?</li>
  <li class="bubble receiver">Not much. Just answering questions on SO</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to use `float` at all! Here's what you do:

```
if (user.id === msgsender.id) {
    $("#messages").append($('<div class="bubble-r"><li>/div>').text(msg));

//I assume bubble-r means you want this bubble on the right

} else {
     $("#messages").append($('<div class="bubble"><li></div>').text(msg));
}
function render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id="messages">
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Then add this in your CSS:

```
.bubble {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.bubble-r {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

This makes the appropriate margins nonexistent, so it will make them attach to that side of the screen.

Comment: div can't be direct child of ul, that's invalid html, plain and simple

Comment: I copied it from the question, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: stil messages are going to append divs? invalid html